# convert HTML response to array or an object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object

I have written an express server that hits the Zaubacorp.com API and gets gets the following result. The result is a **string**

**Result from API:**

```
                <div class="show" align="left" id="company/CHOUDH/U65999MP1985PTC003043">CHOUDH </div>

                <div class="show" align="left" id="company/CHOPRA/U45201CT1982PTC001899">CHOPRA </div>

                <div class="show" align="left" id="company/CHOUDH/U72200UP1996PLC019258">CHOUDH </div>

                <div class="show" align="left" id="company/CHOROSEN-LIMITED/U99999MH1955PLC009659">CHOROSEN LIMITED </div>

                <div class="show" align="left" id="company/CHOLAI-FOUNDATION/U85300TN2019NPL127317">CHOLAI FOUNDATION </div>
```

Now, after I get the API, I need to send this to a react frontend. I need to extract specific value from it like the ID and the company name and send it to a ReactJS frontend. I am not able to extract the value from the given string format.

**Here is my Express controller**

```
post_a_product =  async (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(req.body.query);
    const query = {
        "search": req.body.query,
        "filter":"company"
    }
   var result = await axios.post("https://www.zaubacorp.com/custom-search", query)

    stringData = result.data
try {
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(stringData);
    console.log('====================================');

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
    res.end("We have sent the response")
```

How do I extract the IDs and the Company name from the given string in a format to send to the frontend?

Comment: what is the type of your htmldata ?

Comment: It might be naive on my part, but is there a different endpoint  or an option to return JSON (or another) response?

Comment: Hey @JuhilSomaiya .. I did a typeof on the response and it is a string. I am sorry, I am a new programmer. I still need to extract all ids and company names from this string. How do we do that? Let me modify my answer to reflect the changes

Comment: @SarthakBatra did my answer help you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some html parser. One of it is `https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser`. The code will look like this

```
const {parse} = require('node-html-parser');
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(result.data)));
```

the response will be a proper JSON something like

```
{
    "childNodes": [{
        "childNodes": [{
            "childNodes": [],
            "nodeType": 3,
            "rawText": "CHOUDH "
        }],
        "tagName": "div",
        "rawAttrs": "class=\"show\" align=\"left\" id=\"company/CHOUDH/U65999MP1985PTC003043\"",
        "parentNode": null,
        "classNames": ["show"],
        "nodeType": 1,
        "id": "company/CHOUDH/U65999MP1985PTC003043"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [],
        "nodeType": 3,
        "rawText": "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [{
            "childNodes": [],
            "nodeType": 3,
            "rawText": "CHOPRA "
        }],
        "tagName": "div",
        "rawAttrs": "class=\"show\" align=\"left\" id=\"company/CHOPRA/U45201CT1982PTC001899\"",
        "parentNode": null,
        "classNames": ["show"],
        "nodeType": 1,
        "id": "company/CHOPRA/U45201CT1982PTC001899"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [],
        "nodeType": 3,
        "rawText": "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [{
            "childNodes": [],
            "nodeType": 3,
            "rawText": "CHOUDH "
        }],
        "tagName": "div",
        "rawAttrs": "class=\"show\" align=\"left\" id=\"company/CHOUDH/U72200UP1996PLC019258\"",
        "parentNode": null,
        "classNames": ["show"],
        "nodeType": 1,
        "id": "company/CHOUDH/U72200UP1996PLC019258"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [],
        "nodeType": 3,
        "rawText": "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [{
            "childNodes": [],
            "nodeType": 3,
            "rawText": "CHOROSEN LIMITED "
        }],
        "tagName": "div",
        "rawAttrs": "class=\"show\" align=\"left\" id=\"company/CHOROSEN-LIMITED/U99999MH1955PLC009659\"",
        "parentNode": null,
        "classNames": ["show"],
        "nodeType": 1,
        "id": "company/CHOROSEN-LIMITED/U99999MH1955PLC009659"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [],
        "nodeType": 3,
        "rawText": "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t"
    }, {
        "childNodes": [{
            "childNodes": [],
            "nodeType": 3,
            "rawText": "CHOLAI FOUNDATION "
        }],
        "tagName": "div",
        "rawAttrs": "class=\"show\" align=\"left\" id=\"company/CHOLAI-FOUNDATION/U85300TN2019NPL127317\"",
        "parentNode": null,
        "classNames": ["show"],
        "nodeType": 1,
        "id": "company/CHOLAI-FOUNDATION/U85300TN2019NPL127317"
    }],
    "tagName": null,
    "rawAttrs": "",
    "parentNode": null,
    "classNames": [],
    "nodeType": 1,
    "valid": true
}
```

This has all the necessary info you need. Hope this helps.